# Performance for table length operator

Tags: c, performance, lua, lua-table

Lua has the `#` operator to compute the "length" of a table being used as an array. In a language such as C, after you've computed the length of something, you typically don't compute it again. e.g. `int len = strlen(string);`

Is this any different in Lua? Is one less efficient than the other?

(Obviously this probably won't show a *noticeable* difference for fairly small tables, but it's never bad to know.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The value of `#` for a table is not stored internally by Lua: it is computed every time it is called.

Lua uses a binary search and so the cost is logarithmic in the size of the table. See the code at http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/ltable.c.html#luaH_getn. In other words, the cost is essentially constant, except for huge tables.