# Creating arrays in Lua from list returned by gmatch

Tags: arrays, string, lua, lua-table, lua-patterns

I am programming in Lua and so far I have this.

```
S=tostring(M[i].AllSegmentsList)      --it returns "MSH, PID"
for i in string.gmatch(S, ",") do      --I have  ", " as delimiter 
  t= {}        --Now, I want the values returned by delimiter to be added into an array.
end
```

How can I do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declare the table before, and add the elements in the loop like this:

```
local t = {}
for i in S:gmatch("([^,%s]+)") do  
    t[#t + 1] = i
end
```

The pattern `[^,%s]+` matches one or more non-comma, non-space characters.

Comment: `%w` assumes the items are words formed with letter and digits, which is fine for the example given, but may not be general enough.

Comment: @lhf I changed it to `[^,%s]+`, hopefully that satisfies the OP's needs.

Comment: I would not recommend the `t[#t + 1]` approach. It's better to store the current index in a local variable. With #t Lua has to compute the length of the table at each iteration.

Comment: @W.B. If the table is large, I agree with you. I'm using `#` operator because it's more clear and in most cases, the table is small, so the performance is not an issue.

Comment: Thank you so much , it totally worked. But, can you please please please explain how is "([^,%s]+)" part working? I really need to now this. Thank you

Comment: I know I'm kinda late, but why not use table.insert(t, i)? Does it introduce significant overhead?

Comment: @Xerus Both are OK to use.

Comment: This answer here confirms what @W.B. said, that the length operator `#` isn't free, it does some calculations each time it's called. This answer here points to the relevant Lua interpreter source code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18208085/4206247 (and if you use LuaJIT, the relevant code is this: https://github.com/LuaJIT/LuaJIT/blob/v2.1/src/lj_tab.c#L640-L686)